# execute code on load in vb.net aspx page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I appreciate help for this issue which stoled a lot of hours.
I have this code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Label1.Text = "924 695 302"
    Label2.Text = "690 142 449"

    Dim ipvisitante = Request.ServerVariables("remote_addr")

    Dim hoje = DateTime.Now

    Dim informacao = ipvisitante & " --- " & hoje

    'Send e-mail

    Dim strFrom = "fernandopessoa@fpessoa.net"  ''IMPORTANT: This must be same as your smtp authentication address.
    Dim strTo = "francopessoa.espana@hotmail.com"
    Dim MailMsg As New MailMessage(New MailAddress(strFrom.Trim()), New MailAddress(strTo))
    MailMsg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.Default
    MailMsg.Subject = "This is a test"
    MailMsg.Body = "This is a sample message using SMTP authentication"
    MailMsg.Priority = MailPriority.High
    MailMsg.IsBodyHtml = True
    'Smtpclient to send the mail message 

    Dim SmtpMail As New SmtpClient
    Dim basicAuthenticationInfo As New Net.NetworkCredential("fernandopessoa@fpessoa.net", "---------")

    ''IMPORANT:  Your smtp login email MUST be same as your FROM address.

    SmtpMail.Host = "mail.fpessoa.net"
    SmtpMail.UseDefaultCredentials = False
    SmtpMail.Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo


    MsgBox("O ficheiro existe", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "SIM")



    'Write to txt File

    FileOpen(1, "visitas.txt", OpenMode.Append)
    WriteLine(1, informacao)
    FileClose()


End Sub
```

Now, when the page Loads, the text apears in the Labels.
Surprisingly, it doesn't execute the rest of the code, Display Msgbox, Write to the .txt File and send the e-mail.

Can anyone give me a clue of what's going wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you are mixing winforms and webforms code together. Don't do that.

Comment: I think so too. I'm knew with aspx vb.net. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code does execute... it runs on the *Web Server*. It does **not** run in the client's web browser, and never will.

That explains the MsBox() and file, though the web server may also be getting hung up waiting for someone to click "Okay" on a MsgBox no one will ever see. For the e-mail, you never call `SmtpMail.Send(MailMsg)`

While I'm here, that file code is using an antique api.

---

It sounds like you need a quick primer on how this all works, so here is what happens step by step:

1. User clicks a link to your page or types your page address in their address bar.
2. The browser sends an **HTTP request** to your server.
3. Your server receives the request, creates a *new instance* of your page class in a worker thread.
4. Code runs in your page class for ALL phases of the [ASP.Net Page Lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) .
5. The ASP.Net runtime uses your page class instance to render an **HTTP response** (usually in html) and send it to the browser.
6. *Your page class instance is destroyed*.
7. The browser receives the response, parses a new Document Object Model (DOM), and renders that DOM to the display.
8. The user sees and interacts with your page, causing a post-back.
9. Go to step 2, taking special note of the "*new instance*" phrase when you reach step 3.

Comment: Thank you Joel. Why it doesn't run? I already tried without the msgbox, but it didn't work also.

Comment: Again... it **does** run. It runs on the _web server_. That is where **all** VB code runs. The ASP.Net run time uses your page class to build up a document tree it will then render to HTML and send to the browser, and once that happens the instance of your page class is destroyed. No code you write in this class is ever sent to the user, because the user might not even have the .Net framework installed. It's only used to generate an html response to an http request.

Comment: If that's so, why it puts the text in the textboxes?

Comment: Because the textboxes are data in the document tree. The render phase will see the values of those text properties and render them to html. But that's just data. Calling `MsgBox()` is a behavior, and you can render a behavior like that in html. Html is just a static document.

Comment: The server creates the page and the 'Loading' is the server loading the page and generating a HTML response (which can include modifying the controls prior to sending the response to the client). The events and and subsequent modification are result of the client posting the pages data back to the server, the server 'Loading' the page, and generating an updated response.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your comments. I really don't know how to achieve my goal. Best regards. Fernando Pessoa

Comment: I understand all the process. What I want is to have a register of my visitors, and I know how to do it with PHP. But, with this language, I got stuck. I need to think in another way to do it.

Comment: In PHP, you'd use javascript to show a message box (possibly via jquery UI). You need to do the same thing here.

Comment: My point is not the Message Box. I only used it to test the code, as I wasn't geting the e-mail and the data writen to the to .txt file.

Comment: The MsgBox() might be blocking the remaining code from finishing, but as I noted, it was never actually sending the e-mail, and the file might not be written to the location you expect.